# Irrefutable/lazy pattern exercise in Haskell wikibook

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, lazy-evaluation, strictness

Half way down here...

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Laziness

...is an exercise asking about the effects of changes to an alternative implementation of the `head` function that uses irrefutable patterns. It provides a definition of `head'` as follows, noting that it will always return `undefined` due to irrefutable matching of the first equation:

```
head' :: [a] -> a
head' ~[]     = undefined
head' ~(x:xs) = x
```

Then it asks:

- Why won't changing the order of the equations to `head'` help here?
- If the first equation is changed to use an ordinary refutable pattern,
  will the behavior of `head'` still be different from that of `head`? If
  so, how?

In GHC 7.8.4 it seems that changing the order "helps" at least to the extent of making this function behave like the regular partial version of `head`, albeit with a different exception in the empty list case. The answer to the second question would appear to me to be "no", but given the "if so, how" addendum, it feels like I must be missing something here too. Can anyone enlighten me? The solutions link on the page does not cover this exercise unfortunately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what the wikibook means by "help".  You are correct that changing the order will make it behave essentially like the normal `head`.  Similarly, you are correct that making the first pattern refutable would also make it behave like `head`.  I'm going to say that these questions are confused; they are definitely confusing.

We can verify these answers by calculation (including calculation with GHC):

```
head [] = ⊥
head (x:xs) = x
head ⊥ = ⊥

head' [] = ⊥
head' (x:xs) = ⊥
head' ⊥ = ⊥

head1 [] = ⊥
head1 (x:xs) = x
head1 ⊥ = ⊥

head2 [] = ⊥
head2 (x:xs) = x
head2 ⊥ = ⊥
```

`head` is the standard library version. `head'` is the version from the wikibook. `head1` is the version with the clauses swapped. `head2` is the version with the first pattern being a refutable match against `[]`. ⊥ is read as "bottom" and represents a non-terminating or exceptional computation, i.e. `undefined`.

What I would've expected is examples like the following where there are subtle but significant differences between refutable and irrefutable patterns:

```
konst ~() = ()

konst' () = ()

partialId ~(x:xs) = x:xs

partialId' (x:xs) = x:xs
```

Comment: With belated thanks for your helpful answer and apologies for any other breaches of etiquette in returning here over 2 years later, I've been looking again at the final part of your answer and am at a loss to find any way of obtaining a different result from partialId versus partialId' for any input I can think of. Would you be able to point out the difference to me please? (I see the difference between the two konst variants clearly enough.)